# Summing up numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello want to know how to use PostgreSQL to sum() "CALL ID count" and then have the result on the bottom of the list. I have tried union and group by.

```
AGENT   CALL ID count
xxxxx   13
xxxxx   21
xxxxx   49
xxxxx   58
xxxxx   67
xxxxx   32
xxxxx   9
xxxxx   8
xxxxx   39
xxxxx   1047
```

to say

```
AGENT   CALL ID count
xxxxx   13
xxxxx   21
xxxxx   49
xxxxx   58
xxxxx   67
xxxxx   32
xxxxx   9
xxxxx   8
xxxxx   39
xxxxx   1047
TOTAL   1343

Select Agent,Sum("CALL ID count") as TOTAL 
from AgentCount 
group by "CALL ID count" 
order by Agent
```

Im hoping to get the agent name's with there count and then the total at the end
Thank you

Comment: remove group by , you are good to go

Comment: yes that works but gives me just the sum im hoping to get the agent name's with there count and then the total at the end

Comment: group by agent instead and do union , so you will have two unions.

Comment: Postgres doesnt have ROLLUP,amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a UNION to merge the two queries and then use ORDER BY accordingly, take a look at the example below :

```
Select Agent,Sum("CALL ID count") as TOTAL 
from AgentCount 
group by Agent 
UNION
Select 'TOTAL' AS Agent ,Sum("CALL ID count") as TOTAL FROM AgentCount 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Agent = 'TOTAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC, Agent
```

Comment: Ok look good the "order by case when" is not working im my ZOHO but i will tweak it a bit. but i like it.